# RabbitMQ - How to Detect consumer queue has been destroyed?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

all
  I am developing application in which client is creating queue with rabbitmq server, and there is also another server that will manage all the calculation over server.

I am facing problem with detection of queue destroy at server side. 
For example : queue with name "a" created from android client, and now user is going to kill the app, that time queue will destroy. but server still in unknown state of that queue. so i am want to listen any event or any method to call for detect queue has been destroy from client side.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Consumer Cancel Notification](http://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-cancel.html).

If you're using the [node-amqp](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp) module, you should set the `consumer_cancel_notify` to true and, while subscribing to a queue, check for `basicCancel`.

```
q.subscribe(function (message, headers, deliveryInfo, messageObject) {
    // Check for basicCancel
});
```

Comment: Means i also have to subscribe to queue from server side? if client creating queue with name "a", then server also need to create queue and subscribe to it?? i am using node-amqp library. Thanks

Comment: @HiteshArtoon Your client subscribes to the queue he creates ? That's weird. Usually you have a client pushing messages into a queue and another client (your server for instance) subscribing to it and receiving notifications.

Comment: Can you please put here sample client server nodejs script. i am thinking that if i subscribe that queue from server that will create socket connection. so in future load will rise the failure.